# Manipulate more javascript array based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've a strange thing to do but I don't know how to start

I start with this vars

```
var base = [1,1,1,2,3,5,7,9,14,19,28,40,56,114,232,330];
var sky = [0,0,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,17];
var ite = [64,52,23,38,13,15,6,4,6,3,2,1,2,1,1,1];
```

So to start all the 3 array have the same length and the very first operation is to see if there is a duplicate value in sky array, in this case the 0 is duplicated and only in this case is at the end, but all of time the sky array is sorted. So I've to remove all the duplicate (in this case 0) from sky and remove the corresponding items from base and sum the corresponding items on ite. So if there's duplicate on position 4,5 I've to manipulate this conditions. But let see the new 3 array:

```
var new_base = [1,2,3,5,7,9,14,19,28,40,56,114,232,330];
var new_sky = [0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,17];
var new_ite = [139,38,13,15,6,4,6,3,2,1,2,1,1,1];
```

If you see the new_ite have 139 instead the 64,52,23, that is the sum of 64+52+23, because the first 3 items on sky are the same (0) so I remove two corresponding value from base and sky too and I sum the corresponding value into the new_ite array.

There's a fast way to do that? I thought a for loops but I stuck at the very first for (i = 0; i < sky.length; i++) lol, cuz I've no idea on how to manipulate those 3 array in that way

J

Comment: Does time matter on this? Will it be used on HUGE arrays? Are there memory constraints(Can we duplicate the array to quick sort it?)?

Comment: Do you have to work with these arrays provided? Or can you change how these arrays are stored and represented? If these arrays are really related to each other in the way that you are describing it might make more sense to have a single array of objects and each object would have a base value, sky value, and ite value.

Comment: Is the array always presorted?

Comment: @Grallen arr sky and base are always sorted and performance is important for me, but huge array no, maybe 100 or 200 items max. for tj-rockefeller I can duplicate, those array are related each other but is populated in 3 different actions and part of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When removing elements from an array during a loop, the trick is to start at the end and move to the front. It makes many things easier.

```
for( var i = sky.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (sky[i] == prev) {
        // Remove previous index from base, sky
        // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript
        base.splice(i+1, 1);
        sky.splice(i+1, 1);

        // Do sum, then remove
        ite[i] += ite[i+1];
        ite.splice(i+1, 1);
    }
    prev = sky[i];
}
```

I won't speak to whether this is the "fastest", but it does work, and it's "fast" in terms of requiring little programmer time to write and understand. (Which is often the most important kind of fast.)

Comment: Tnx, for now this seems the fastest solution

Answer (score 0):

atltag's answer is fastest.  Please see:

https://repl.it/FBpo/5

Comment: Tnx for this, but why start with the new array?

Comment: I figured the new arrays were copies to protect the original data. What I did here was destructive to the arrays;

Comment: You said speed is important(like you might be running this many times per second).  I think it's faster to build new arrays than to split multiple times.  I'm going to test then update my answer.

Comment: Not many time for second but I've a small ammount of time to do all! Btw, your script start with the solution array, not with the starting one

Comment: New fast answer posted.

Comment: Tnx for your reply, if I'm not wrong your solution is good but not the fastest, see this speed test https://repl.it/FBnH/1 your is on option3, right now the alttag is the fastest one. If I'm not wrong

Comment: The speed test is not entirely fair, as my solution edits in place, rather than creating new variables (which isn't correct for when the test runs option 3), and also means there are no new arrays created on successive runs of my solution.

Comment: One simple place for speedup is avoiding having to dereference `.length` each iteration. Going backward avoids this.

Comment: Yes his does seem faster.  I'm going to verify my logic.  I may have made a mistake.  My initial tests of split vs building a new array showed a big advantage to building a new array.  I'll verify and then edit my answer.

Comment: All I meant is that the speed test is borked, and goosed in my favor (as no changes to the array occur on successive runs), not that my solution was necessarily faster. The test would likely give different results if the modified-in-place arrays were reset before each run.

Comment: I believe your answer is faster. I think I created a fair test and I think my code is optimal.  See the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this solution where *j* is used as index for the new arrays, and *i* for the original arrays:

```js
var base = [1,1,1,2,3,5,7,9,14,19,28,40,56,114,232,330];
var sky = [0,0,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,17];
var ite = [64,52,23,38,13,15,6,4,6,3,2,1,2,1,1,1];

var new_base = [], new_sky = [], new_ite = [];

var j = -1;
sky.forEach(function (sk, i) {
    if (!i || sk !== sky[i-1]) {
        new_ite[++j] = 0;
        new_base[j] = base[i];
        new_sky[j] = sk;
    }
    new_ite[j] += ite[i];
});

console.log('new_base = ' + new_base);
console.log('new_sky = ' + new_sky);
console.log('new_ite = ' + new_ite);
```

Comment: Tnx tricot is a start :D

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean with "a start". Is there something I missed?

Comment: Sorry is not refered to your work, is a start for me :D this's only a starting point for me, now I've to do other things with those data and is more "complicated" I'll open a new post, tnx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#reduce` to create new arrays from the originals according to the rules:

```js
var base = [1,1,1,2,3,5,7,9,14,19,28,40,56,114,232,330];
var sky = [0,0,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,17];
var ite = [64,52,23,38,13,15,6,4,6,3,2,1,2,1,1,1];

var result = sky.reduce(function(r, n, i) {
  var last = r.sky.length - 1;
  
  if(n === r.sky[last]) {
    r.ite[last] += ite[i];
  } else {
    r.base.push(base[i]);
    r.sky.push(n);
    r.ite.push(ite[i]);
  }
  
  return r;
}, { base: [], sky: [], ite: [] });

console.log('new base:', result.base.join(','));
console.log('new sky:', result.sky.join(','));
console.log('new ite:', result.ite.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with a single `.reduce()` in O(n) time you can do as follows; (I have used array destructuring at the assignment part. One might choose to use three `.push()`s though)

```js
var base = [1,1,1,2,3,5,7,9,14,19,28,40,56,114,232,330],
     sky = [0,0,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,17],
     ite = [64,52,23,38,13,15,6,4,6,3,2,1,2,1,1,1],
 results = sky.reduce((r,c,i) => c === r[1][r[1].length-1] ? (r[2][r[2].length-1] += ite[i],r)
                                                           : ([r[0][r[0].length],r[1][r[1].length],r[2][r[2].length]] = [base[i],c,ite[i]],r),[[],[],[]]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
```

Comment: Tnx, I always love your solutions :D

Comment: All of the solutions thus far have been O(n).

Comment: @alttag Honestly, i wasn't checking the other answers.. But looking into your answer... So you believe three cascaded `.splice(x,1)`s, yet alone one, is O(1) operation..?

Comment: You got me; I was ignoring the cost of `splice()`. Still, it would depend greatly on the internals of the particular Javascript engine. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11535121/1327983) suggests `splice()` is O(n), but a comment on it suggests O(1). Deleting is certainly O(1), the O(n) complexity would come in index reassignment, albeit with a very low constant modifier in practice. If the goal were low O(), one could set values to null instead of deleting/reassigning, then recreate, thus O(2n) = O(n), but that sounds slower. I like the elegance of your answer, btw.