# How to move array items to up or down using JavaScript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following json

```
{  "EmployeeLists": [
{
  "ID": 1,
  "NAME": "Anand",
  "Salary": 90000
},
{
  "ID": 2,
  "NAME": "Anbu",
  "Salary": 80000 
},
{
  "ID": 3,
  "NAME": "Bala",
  "Salary": 85000
}  ]}
```

I want to move the array item 2 to up or down. the expected output is like below.

```
{  "EmployeeLists": [
{
  "ID": 2,
  "NAME": "Anbu",
  "Salary": 80000
},
{
  "ID": 1,
  "NAME": "Anand",
  "Salary": 90000
},
{
  "ID": 3,
  "NAME": "Bala",
  "Salary": 85000
} ]}
```

Comment: You can do it by the swap function.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011629/swapping-two-items-in-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 4):

You can swap the 2 elements like so:

```
var x = EmployeeLists[2];
EmployeeLists[2] = EmployeeLists[1];
EmployeeLists[1] = x;
```