# How to change position of object inside array?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have array of objects like this:

```
rows = [{"sortOrder": 1, "name": "A"}, {"sortOrder": 2, "name": "B"}, {"sortOrder": 3, "name": "C"}]
```

When I click up button I call this function passing object `{"sortOrder": 2, "name": "B"}` as parameter:

```
public rowUp(item:any) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++) {
      if(this.rows[i].sortOrder == item.sortOrder) {
        this.rows[i].sortOrder = this.rows[i].sortOrder - 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

In result I need to change `sortOrder` of all objects pressing buttons `up/down`

I tried to do this another way:

```
public rowUp(item: any) {
    let currentIndex = item.sortOrder;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++) {
      if (this.rows[i].sortOrder == item.sortOrder) {
        this.rows[i].sortOrder = this.rows[i].sortOrder - 1;
        this.rows[i - 1].sortOrder = currentIndex;

      }
    }
  }

  public rowDown(item: any) {
    let currentIndex = item.sortOrder;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++) {
      if (this.rows[i].sortOrder == item.sortOrder) {
        this.rows[i].sortOrder = this.rows[i].sortOrder + 1;
        this.rows[i + 1].sortOrder = currentIndex;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you're facing? You want to change `sortOrder` up/down, and then sort the array according to the new order values?

Comment: use destructuring an array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523934/typescript-swap-array-items

Comment: Yes, but it works unstable, I think I do something wrong.

Comment: There is no need to iterate all items. Based on the selected item and selected order, just swap `name` with item above or below.

Comment: Object can contains more properties than, not only `name`