# Exchange position of 2 array elements in Python

Tags: python, arrays, random, shuffle

Is there any easy way to exchange the position of 2 elements - or better yet, n elements - in an array?

I came up with some code, but it looks quite ugly and the performance should be a bit bad:

```
chromo = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]

gene1Pos = random.randrange(0, len(chromo)-1, 1)
gene2Pos = random.randrange(0, len(chromo)-1, 1)
tmpGene1 = chromo[gene1Pos]
tmpGene2 = chromo[gene2Pos]
chromo[gene1Pos] = tmpGene2
chromo[gene2Pos] = tmpGene1
```

This should work, but well, it's not nice. The better way would be a routine like **random.shuffle** but that instead of mixing everything would mix just a number n of elements. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
>>> chromo[gene1Pos], chromo[gene2Pos] = chromo[gene2Pos], chromo[gene1Pos]
```

So you just need to make sure you have the right genXPos

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554130/fastest-way-to-swap-elements-in-python-list for discussion of what this compiles to and why it's the fastest.

Comment: Thank you. This is a bit prettier and as dkamins points out, faster.

Answer (score 1):

Just combine the normal mechanism for swapping variables in Python with slicing/slice assignment.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a[2:3], a[4:5] = a[4:5], a[2:3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with what you're doing.  You can simplify it by removing one of the temp variables though.  To swap `a` and `b`, all you need is this:

```
tmp = a
a = b
b = tmp
```

Comment: No, no, no! This is not Python you are thinking of! In Python, tuple unpacking and tuple assignment allows you to write: `a,b = b,a`  Done!

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Agreed. See my comment on your answer (which I upvoted) re performance (`a,b=b,a` is fastest).  But swapping via temp is and always will be a classic micro-algorithm to keep in any programmer's toolbox.