# How swapping variables is implemented in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, swap, cpython

How does the below code work in Python:

```
a = input()
b = input()
a, b = b, a  # STATEMENT 1
print(a, b)
```

Does the statement 1 create a third variable in Python heap memory space to swap the two numbers or does it use some algorithm to do the swap?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a standardized method to swap two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python)

Comment: see link for detailed answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462635/python-what-is-the-space-complexity-when-tuple-swap-is-used-in-bubble-sorting)

Comment: under the hood python implements this by having a temporary variable, which by using tuple notation is not visible in this example

Comment: @NikosM That's incorrect.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin No, I didn't get that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple bytecode operation which doesn't need any intermediate variables to do the swap. See this demo:

```
import dis

code = '''
a = input()
b = input()
a, b = b, a
'''

dis.dis(code)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
>  2           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (input)
>              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
>              4 STORE_NAME               1 (a)
>
>  3           6 LOAD_NAME                0 (input)
>              8 CALL_FUNCTION            0
>             10 STORE_NAME               2 (b)
>
>  4          12 LOAD_NAME                2 (b)
>             14 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
>             16 ROT_TWO
>             18 STORE_NAME               1 (a)
>             20 STORE_NAME               2 (b)
>             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
>             24 RETURN_VALUE
> ```

Note: Like bytecode as a whole, this is of course just an implementation detail of CPython.

Comment: Technicaly speaking `ROT_TWO` swaps the top 2 values of the python stack VM. The `ROT_TWO` implementation, code tcan be found on CPython's repository. In a sense the role of the 3rd variable for swapping is played by the top of the stack.

Comment: @NikosM. `Technicaly speaking ROT_TWO swaps the top 2 values of the python stack` And does my post somehow conflict with this..? `In a sense the role of the 3rd variable for swapping is played by the top of the stack.` This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: No my friend your post does not conflict with that. I am simply trying to point out that the top of the stack plays the role of the 3rd variable for swapping the values. Simple as that

Comment: In fact I have upvoted your post, it is excellent! But out of curiosity I delved into the ROT_TWO implementation to see how it works. Thats all

Comment: @NikosM. Oukkei 

Comment: Officialy here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L1535. As a matter of fact 4 memory locations are used for ROT_TWO implementation not even 3 (the minimum). Two stack locations and two variable locations.

Comment: See my [complementary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62038590/3591273) to yours

Comment: @NikosM. Nice stuff :)

Answer (score 8):

[ruohola](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61976508/3591273) did a good job in providing the translated bytecode of the python code.

I am duplicating here for reference:

Python code:

```
a = input()
b = input()
a, b = b, a  # STATEMENT 1
print(a, b)
```

Bytecode:

```
 2           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (input)
             2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             4 STORE_NAME               1 (a)

 3           6 LOAD_NAME                0 (input)
             8 CALL_FUNCTION            0
            10 STORE_NAME               2 (b)

 4          12 LOAD_NAME                2 (b)
            14 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
            16 ROT_TWO                  # swapping done here
            18 STORE_NAME               1 (a)
            20 STORE_NAME               2 (b)
            22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            24 RETURN_VALUE
```

`ROT_TWO` operation swaps the top 2 values of the python stack. So what do we actually have so far:

> **Python swaps the 2 values by calling a `swap` (`ROT_TWO`) subroutine.**

If this is how far you want to go and it answers your question it is fine.
However for those who want to go deeper and see how this swap (`ROT_TWO`) subroutine works, [here is the official CPython implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L1535):

```
#define TOP()             (stack_pointer[-1])
#define SECOND()          (stack_pointer[-2])
#define SET_TOP(v)        (stack_pointer[-1] = (v))
#define SET_SECOND(v)     (stack_pointer[-2] = (v))
/*..*/
case TARGET(ROT_TWO): {
   PyObject *top = TOP();
   PyObject *second = SECOND();
   SET_TOP(second);
   SET_SECOND(top);
   FAST_DISPATCH();
}
```

Or in other words the implementation of `ROT_TWO` actually performs the following steps (`a`,`b` are the top 2 values of the stack):

```
x1 = a
x2 = b
a = x2
b = x1
```

So the implementation **uses auxiliary temporary locations** (`x1`, `x2`) and in fact it uses 2 auxilliary memory locations instead of the minimum 1 auxiliary location to swap two values that a more memory-efficient implementation would do:

```
x = a
a = b
b = x
```

Under the current computing model, [swapping two values can be done only in so many different ways](https://geekfactorial.blogspot.com/2016/08/the-many-different-ways-of-swapping-two-numbers.html) and does not happen magically:

1. Using auxilliary temporary storage
2. Employing a series of `XOR` (or similar arithmetic) operations

So to sum it up, Python under the hood indeed uses auxilliary temporary locations in order to swap the two values.

Comment: +1 Nice answer! But I would like to know what you mean by Python stack. Aren't all objects created on the private heap? Where does stack come into the picture?

Comment: The virtual stack of the python machine, see source code, it is implemented as a stack of a virtual machine. In this sense

Comment: What does "stack of a virtual machine" mean?

Comment: The python bytecode is interpreted and ran by a virtual machine implemented in C++ (CPython) as one can see in the linked source code. This virtual machine has or simulates a stack. This is what is meant