# How to change array key in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript swap array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872310/javascript-swap-array-elements)

For example i have an array `var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];` and i wona to replace 1st key to 2nd and my array should start to look like `['two', 'one', 'three'];` how can i do that, it need to me for bubble sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    temp;

temp = arr[1]; // temp is 'two'
arr[1] = arr[0]; // Now it is ['one', 'one', 'three']
arr[0] = temp; // And now it is ['two', 'one', 'three']
```

Just use a temporary variable.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/msD4s/)