# Swapping elements in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, swap

I have an array of objects and I want to swap the position of two elements in the array.
I tried this:

```
var tempObject = array.splice(index, 1, array[index + 1]);
array.splice(index+1, 1, tempObject);
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly as it results in some weird errors. For example, I am unable to use methods of the object. Calling `array[x].getName` results in an error.

Can any body lend a helping hand here?

Just in case it is important, I have used `object.prototype` to add the methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bug in your code is that splice returns an array of items, not a single item. Since you are extracting a single item, you could do:

```
var tempObject = array.splice(index, 1, array[index + 1])[0]; // get the item from the array
array.splice(index+1, 1, tempObject);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872457/1669279) provides a shorter version, also using splice:

```
array[index] = array.splice(index+1, 1, array[index])[0];
```

[Another very interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20601829/1669279) is both short and [fast](http://jsperf.com/js-list-swap/2):

```
function identity(x){return x};

array[index] = identity(array[index+1], array[index+1]=array[index]);
```

Comment: [http://jsperf.com/js-list-swap](http://jsperf.com/js-list-swap) - Using splice is a lot slower than a temporary variable.

Comment: Thanks very much! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/74wy8/1/)

```
var array_of_numbers = [5,4,3,2,1,0],
    swap = function(array,a,b){var tmp=array[a];array[a]=array[b];array[b]=tmp;};
swap(array_of_numbers,0,4);
// array_of_numbers now is [1,4,3,2,5,0]
```

Or you can do add the function to the `Array.prototype`:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/74wy8/2/)

```
Array.prototype.swap = function(a,b){ var tmp=this[a];this[a]=this[b];this[b]=tmp;};
var array_of_numbers = [5,4,3,2,1,0];
array_of_numbers.swap(0,4);
// array_of_numbers now is [1,4,3,2,5,0]
```