# Searching nested array elements in mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

i have collection called 'test' in that there is a document like:

```
{
"_id" : 1
"letters" : [ 
        [ "A", "B" ], 
        [ "C", "D" ], 
        [ "A", "E", "B", "F" ]
    ]
}
```

if i search like this:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"_id" : 1}, {"letters": ["A", "B"] })
```

then it will fetch the record.

```
{
"_id" : 1
"letters" : [ 
        [ "A", "B" ], 
        [ "C", "D" ], 
        [ "A", "E", "B", "F" ]
    ]
}
```

if i search like this:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"_id" : 1}, {"letters": ["B", "A"] })
```

it doesn't fetch the record

my requirment is if im give like this also (["B", "A"]), it have to fetch the document. Because the same letters are already present in the array.

i will try with $all operator but it doesn't work

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"_id" : 1}, {"letters": {$all: ["B", "A"]} })
```

now also it will not fetch the record

could anyone can please give the solution.

Comment: if you use update, that second param is not your condition

Comment: OP:   You have two distinct things going on here:  update and query.   Perhaps you can separate them and describe your desired output?

Comment: check this [how to change order of array with mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810951/how-to-change-order-of-array-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
 db.test.find(
       {
        "$and":[
         {"_id" : ObjectId("5a16674b4828c9f51d3b3a18")},
         {"$or":[{"letters": ["A", "B"] },{"letters": ["B", "A"] }]}
               ]
       }
      )
```

Now it will search the document who has `["A","B"] OR ["B","A"]`.

Comment: While this will work, if the letters to match increase in count, this solution will become too complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
    db.getCollection('test').find(
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            'letters':{
                $elemMatch:{
                    $elemMatch:{
                        $in:['B','A']
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

This query will find all the documents which has array elements you specify in last $in close,
example,
It will find same document if you specify only $in:['C'] or $in:['B','A']