# mongo change $position of an array element after addition

Tags: mongodb

With mongo 3.6

`$position` is for mongo `$push`

how do i change the position of the existing element of array.

```
{
"name":"a",
"arr":[
   {_id:1, val:1},
   {_id:3, val:3},
   {_id:2, val:2},
]
}
```

need to change the position of the 3rd element to second

Comment: You can always overwrite the whole document (if all else fails)

Comment: eee ?? that's risky .. as someone else may be updating something else ..

Comment: You can overwrite just the `arr`. It's no less risky than blindly shifting item at pos 3 to pos 2 (when other code might have done so milliseconds ago)

Comment: eee?? even that's risky .. it has to be simpler .. as someone may still be updating other part of arr

Comment: mongodb read is parallel but write is serial. No two write request processed at the same time @andNn

Comment: read is parallel .. which means if 2 people read the data at the same time .. but update at different time.. example .. first one added an obj  {_id :4, val:4} to arr. And then the second one reordered it .. this change ( adding of 4 ) will be complete lost

Comment: Will it be run with the mongo shell or a javascript driver (mongoose)?

Comment: via node.js .. but not mongoose

Comment: can you give some ref code to solve the issue

Comment: I think this might help: [How to change order of array with MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35813305/9297144)

Comment: What is the use case ? Are you trying to fix the data to have sorted order in array ? Something like `db.col.update(    { },    { $push: { arr: { $each: [add elements(optional)], $sort: {_id:1}}}})` should work.

Comment: not sorting .. just reordering .. as per customer requirements

Answer (score 0):

Not possible the way the question imply. There are no atomic operations to reorder embedded documents and no transactions in current v3.6.

The comments suggest the real question is how to reorder subdocuments safely considering possible concurrent writes.

You can implement optimistic locking on application level:

```
const uid = process.pid + '-' + process.hrtime();

// lock the document for updates
db.collection.updateOne({_id, reordering: {$exists: false}}, {$set: {reordering: uid}})
.then(res=>{
    if (res.result.nModified !== 1) {
        throw new Error("concurent reordering or wrong _id")
    }
})
.then(()=>db.collection.findOne({_id, reordering:uid}))
.then(doc=>{
    if (!doc) {
        throw new Error("concurent write")
    }
    // reorder
    doc.arr.splice(1, 0, doc.arr.splice(2, 1)[0]);      
    Reflect.deleteProperty(doc, 'reordering');
    // commit and unlock
    return db.collection.replaceOne({_id, reordering: uid}, doc)
})
.then(res=>{
    if (res.result.nModified !== 1) {
        throw new Error("concurrent write")
    }
})
```

It requires a bit of housekeeping to clear residual locks if an application died somewhere between `updateOne` and `replaceOne` though.

It's up to you how to catch exceptions - you can retry few times, or give up immediately.

Comment: Hi Alex , Thanks for the effort,, but was looking for something stable.

Comment: It is quite stable -  the simplified version of [2 phase commits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/index.html). What are your concerns?

Comment: what if the application craaashes after getting the lock ,, is it recoverable

Comment: It's totally up to you. The lock is implemented on application level, so it is totally under your control - how much efforts you can put into recoverability. `a bit of housekeeping` in the answer is for you to decide what to do with orphaned locks. The `const uid = process.pid + '-' + process.hrtime();` is not a random number exactly for this reason.