# Mongoose Change Order of Array of Objects not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There is a person `Michael` who has `favoriteFruits = [ { name: 'Apple'}, {name: 'Banana'} ]`

What I want to do is changing its order

`[ { name: 'Apple'}, {name: 'Banana'} ]`

**to**

`[ { name: 'Banana'}, {name: 'Apple'} ]`

So I did :

```
Members.findOne({ name: 'Michael' }, function(err, member){
    member.favoriteFruits = [ {name: 'Banana'}, {name: 'Apple'} ]

    member.save(function (err, result){

        // result is favoriteFruits = [ { name: 'Banana'}, {name: 'Apple'} ]
        // result is correct, but real db's order not changed.

    })
})
```

Even `result`'s order of `favoriteFruits` is correct, but the order of db is not changed. The order is not changed.

I guess **MongoDB** assume this job is useless task so it doesn't do anything. How can I update order?

Comment: Array should preserve the order.

Comment: Apart from the result issue, why you are not using `findOneAndUpdate ` instead of two separate queries?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal So is there a way to accomplish it?

Comment: @Ved Sometimes I use, sometimes not. Especially when I have to handle something with queried data.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Perhaps should I add another key value pair such as `[{ name: 'Banana', index: 0`, { name: 'Apple', index: 1 }] and order by index...? I hope there will be more simple way....

Comment: It's probably not mongodb but mongoose that is not handling the update correctly. try this: `member.markModified('favoriteFruits');` before saving.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810951/how-to-change-order-of-array-with-mongodb

Comment: @chridam it's not a duplicate, he is asking for Mongoose specifically and it's a problem with Mongoose specifically.

Comment: @nijm I know that's why I said "possible" because you can use the same concepts in MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Mongoose is not noticing the difference between the arrays. You can tell Mongoose that the field has actually been modified by using the [`Document.prototype.markModified()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified) method.

For your example:

```
Members.findOne({ name: 'Michael' }, function(err, member) {
    member.favoriteFruits = [{ name: 'Banana' }, { name: 'Apple' }];
    member.markModified('favoriteFruits');

    member.save(function (err, result) {

    });
});
```