# Swap columns in a one-dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to swap 2 columns from a delimited text, but the farthest I got is grabbing the first column. This is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
// Input
A1—B1—C1
A2—B2—C2
A3—B3—C3
```

Swap column #1 with column #3. Delimiter is "—".

```
// Result
C1—B1—A1
C2—B2—A2
C3—B3—A3
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3q3q835/4/)

```
  var text = $('#input').val().split("\n");

  var delimiter = "—";
  var col_1 = $('#col_1').val() - 1;
  var col_2 = $('#col_2').val() - 1;

  var out = [];
  var col_arr = [];
  var col = '';

  // Get first column
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    col_arr = text[i].split(delimiter);
    col = col_arr[col_1];
    if (col != undefined) col = col;
    else col = '';
    out[i] = col;
  }

  text = out.join('\n');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple [swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872310/javascript-swap-array-elements) with a `temp` variable. I've used [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the `text` array, but you can replace it with a `for...loop.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var delimiter = "—";
  var rowDelimiter = "\n";
  var text = $('#input').val()
    .trim() // remove white space before and after the text
    .split(rowDelimiter);
  
  var col_1 = $('#col_1').val() - 1;
  var col_2 = $('#col_2').val() - 1;
  
  // check the cols to be a number between 0 and the amount of columns
  // and notify user if their not

  var result = text.map(function(row) {
    var arr = row.split(delimiter);
    
    var temp = arr[col_1]; // cache the value of col_1
    arr[col_1] = arr[col_2]; // set the value of col_2 1 to be that of column 2
    arr[col_2] = temp; // set the value of col_2 to be the value of temp
    
    return arr.join(delimiter);
  }).join(rowDelimiter);

  $('#output').val(result);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px
}

button {
  margin: 10px 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Swap col #<input id="col_1" value="2"> with col #<input id="col_2" value="3">

<br>

<textarea id="input">
A1—B1—C1—D1
A2—B2—C2—D2
A3—B3—C3—D3
</textarea>

<button>Swap</button>

<textarea id="output">

</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

You've successfully split the text into an array of its constituent parts using `split`, you can now use the `reverse` Array function to reverse the order, and then rejoin all the parts together using the `join` Array function and your delimiter.

This simplifies your code in your `for` loop to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  out[i] = text[i].split(delimiter).reverse().join(delimiter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

split() returns an array, so what you can do is first processing your text data to an actual array so its easier to work on it :

```
function getArrayFromInput(){
  var arr = [];
  var lines = $('#input').val().split("\n");
  for (let line of lines){
    let column = line.split('—');
    arr.push(column);
  }
  return arr;
}
//returns [['A1','B1','C1'],['A2','B2','C2'],['A3','B3','C3']]
```

It'll be easier to do what you're trying to do then :)

```
function swapColumns(inputArr, col1, col2){
    var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(inputArr)); //get inputArr structure
    for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        //swap the values
        arr[i][col1] = inputArr[i][col2];
        arr[i][col2] = inputArr[i][col1];
    }
    return arr;
}
//return your array with swaped columns
```

I'll then let you handle the array to text conversion !

Feel free to ask any question