# Swapping all elements of an array except for first and last

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

I have an array that looks like this

```
const x = ['A','B','C','D','E']
```

I want to have an elegant function that would shuffle the content of the array but keeps the first or the last element fixed. Something like `customShuffle(x)` which will shuffle the array but ensures that the element `"A"` will be in the first position and the element `"E"` will be at the last position. All other elements are shuffled.

Comment: What have you tried up to this point?

Comment: Some ideas for you... You can use `indexOf` to find your `first` and `last` elements. Use `slice` to remove them from the array. You'll probably need to define some kind of `swap` function to swap the position of two elements. Maybe iterate over the array swapping random indexes using `Math.random`.

Comment: So cut them off and add them back on

Comment: Please check out my answer posted below. You can also find it at the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e738a2ot/6/

Here's an updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e738a2ot/8/

Comment: Probably late to the party, but I added a more functional programming esque answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first and last elements of the array always stay in that same place, you can apply a normal shuffling algorithm, like a modern variation of [Fisher and Yates'](https://exceptionnotfound.net/understanding-the-fisher-yates-card-shuffling-algorithm/), skipping those positions:

```js
function customShuffle(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 3) {
    return arr;
  }
  
  // Note the -2 (instead of -1) and the i > 1 (instead of i > 0):
  
  for (let i = arr.length - 2; i > 1; --i) {
      const j = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(customShuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).join(', '));
console.log(customShuffle(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']).join(', '));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to choose the first and last elements, as you pointed out in your original question, you can do something like this:

1. Find the index of the elements you want to have in the first and last positions first: `firstIndex` and `lastIndex`.
2. If those elements exist (they might not be present), remove them from the array.
3. Apply a shuffling algorithm to the remaining elements (there's no need to also shuffle `first` and `last`).
4. Add the first and last elements back into their place, if you need to.

```js
function customShuffle(arr, first, last) {
  // Find and remove first and last:
  
  const firstIndex = arr.indexOf(first);  
  if (firstIndex !== -1) arr.splice(firstIndex, 1);  
  
  const lastIndex = arr.indexOf(last);
  if (lastIndex !== -1) arr.splice(lastIndex, 1);
  
  // Normal shuffle with the remainign elements using ES6:
  
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
  }
  
  // Add them back in their new position:
  
  if (firstIndex !== -1) arr.unshift(first);
  if (lastIndex !== -1) arr.push(last);
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(customShuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5, 1).join(', '));
console.log(customShuffle(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'E', 'C').join(', '));
console.log(customShuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10, 20).join(', '));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the shuffle algorithm from [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array/12646864#12646864)

You can extend it like this:

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

function customShuffle(array, first, last) {
    if (first) {
      if (last) {
        const updatedArray = shuffle(array).filter(item => item !== first && item !== last);
        return [first, ...updatedArray, last];
      }

    const updatedArray = shuffle(array).filter(item => item !== first);
    return [first, ...updatedArray];
  }

  return shuffle(array);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function which uses [the modern version of the Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) to shuffle the sub-array `x.slice(1, x.length - 1)`, which is `x` with the exclusion of the first and last elements, then adds them back to the shuffled sub-array:

```js
const x = ['A','B','C','D','E'];

function customShuffle(x) {
  var y = x.slice(1, x.length - 1);
  var j, t, i;
  for (i = y.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      t = y[i];
      y[i] = y[j];
      y[j] = t;
  }
  return [x[0]].concat(y).concat(x[x.length-1]);
}

console.log(customShuffle(x));
console.log(customShuffle(x));
console.log(customShuffle(x));
console.log(customShuffle(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this. `first` and `last` params are optional.

Check if `first` is passed and if it is in the array. If so, then remove it from the array. Do the same for the `last`. Shuffle indices of the remaining array. Recreate new array based on the shuffled indices, as well as `first` and `last` arguments.

```js
const shuffle = (arr, first, last) => {
  let firstIn = false;
  let lastIn = false;

  if (first && arr.includes(first)) {
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(first), 1);
    firstIn = true;
  }
  if (last && arr.includes(last)) {
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(last), 1);
    lastIn = true;
  }

  const len = arr.length;
  const used = [];
  while (used.length !== len) {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    if (!used.includes(r)) { used.push(r); }
  }

  const newArr = [];
  if (first && firstIn) { newArr.push(first); }
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    newArr.push(arr[used[i]]);
  }
  if (last && lastIn) { newArr.push(last); }

  return newArr;
}

let arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'];
arr = shuffle(arr);
console.log(arr);
arr = shuffle(arr, 'A');
console.log(arr);
arr = shuffle(arr, 'A', 'B');
console.log(arr);
```

`shuffle(arr);` will shuffle the whole array.
`arr = shuffle(arr, 'A');` will move `A` to the front and shuffle the rest.
`arr = shuffle(arr, 'A', 'B');` will move `A` to the front, `B` to the end, and shuffle the rest.

Word of caution: while this approach is not in-place, it will still mutate the original array, because of the `splice` method.

Answer (score 2):

You could first generate new shuffled array and then check if first and last arguments are provided and take those elements and place them on first and last position.

```js
const x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

function shuffle(arr, first, last) {
  const newArr = arr.reduce((r, e, i) => {
    const pos = parseInt(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    r.splice(pos, 0, e)
    return r;
  }, []);

  if (first) newArr.unshift(newArr.splice(newArr.indexOf(first), 1)[0]);
  if (last) newArr.push(newArr.splice(newArr.indexOf(last), 1)[0])
  return newArr
}


console.log(shuffle(x))
console.log(shuffle(x, "A", "E"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following simple solution.This will shuffle all the elements other than the first and the last element of the array ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e738a2ot/8/)):

```js
const x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
CustomShuffle(x);

function CustomShuffle(x) {

  //shuffle the elements in between first and the last
  var max = x.length - 2;
  var min = 1;
  for (var i = max; i >= min; i--) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    var itemAtIndex = x[randomIndex];
    x[randomIndex] = x[i];
    x[i] = itemAtIndex;
  }

  alert(x);
}
```

In case first and last elements are not in place beforehand, you may try the following ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e738a2ot/6/)):

```
const x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
CustomShuffle(x, first = "B", last = "A");

function CustomShuffle(x, first, last) {

  //position first element correctly
  var indexToSwap = x.indexOf(first);
  if (indexToSwap != 0) {
    x = SwapValuesAtIndices(x, indexToSwap, 0);
  }

  //position last element correctly
  indexToSwap = x.indexOf(last);
  if (indexToSwap != x.length - 1) {
    x = SwapValuesAtIndices(x, indexToSwap, x.length - 1);
  }

  //randomly shuffle the remaining elements in between
  var max = x.length - 2;
  var min = 1;
  for (var i = max; i >= min; i--) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    var itemAtIndex = x[randomIndex];
    x[randomIndex] = x[i];
    x[i] = itemAtIndex;
  }

  alert(x);
}

function SwapValuesAtIndices(array, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
  var temp = array[firstIndex];
  array[firstIndex] = array[secondIndex];
  array[secondIndex] = temp;
  return array;
}
```

Further reading:

- [Shuffling an array](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/shuffling_array_js.htm)
- [Generating a random number in a given
  range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)
- [Swapping elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872310/javascript-swap-array-elements)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. It keeps the first and last elements in place without explicitly defining their values, and builds a new array with the other elements shuffled randomly.

```js
const x = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
const shuffledArray = customShuffle(x);
console.log(shuffledArray);

function customShuffle(arr) {
  let newArray = [];
  const first = arr[0];
  const last = arr[arr.length-1];
  
  //First, remove the 'first' and 'last' values from array:
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] == first || arr[i] == last){
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  
  //Next, add values to the new array at random:
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    const indexToRemove = Math.floor( Math.random() * arr.length );
    const value = arr[indexToRemove];
    arr.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    newArray.push(value);
  }
  
  //Last, add in the 'first' and 'last' values:
  newArray.unshift(first);
  newArray.push(last);
  
  return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you asked for elegant, I like to implement a more functional style of programming here. The code below does what you want. You supple the `shuffle` function with your array, the max number of times you want it shuffled (the higher the number, the better the shuffle is), and `true` to keep the first element in place, `false` to keep the last.

```
function shuffle(array, maxTimes, first) {
    var temp = (first) ? array.reverse().pop() : array.pop();

    Array.from(
        Array(Math.round(Math.random()*maxTimes))
            .keys()).forEach(val => array = array.reduce((acc,val) => 
                (Math.random() > 0.5) ? acc.concat([val]) : [val].concat(acc),[]));

    return (first) ? [temp].concat(array.reverse()) : array.concat([temp]);
}
```

Example usage:

```
shuffle(['A','B','C','D','E'], 10, true);
```

Output: `["A", "C", "D", "B", "E"]`

I hope this is what you're looking for and answers your question.

**Edit**

Turns out you can get the shuffle logic all in **one** line (when removing the unnecessary newlines). When you add the two lines to retain the first or last character, you can essentially create this function with **three** lines of code.

Answer (score -1):

```
    function SpecialShuffle(MyArray)
    {
    var newArray = [];
    var counter=  1;
    for(var i = MyArray.length-1 ; i>-1 ; i--)
    {
    if(i == MyArray.length)
    {
    newArray[i] = MyArray[i]
    }
    else if(i == 0 )
    {
    newArray[i]=MyArray[i];
    }
    else
    {
    newArray[counter] = MyArray[i];
    counter++;
    }
    }
return newArray;
    }
```