# Reorder array to put specific element at given index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var arr = [
   {name: 'Price'},
   {name: 'Sale'},
   {name: 'Shipping'},
   {name: 'Customer Rating'}
]
```

Is there a way to sort this array so that a specific item is at a given index? For example, I always want 'Customer Rating' to be at index 1.

```
var arr = [
   {name: 'Price'},
   {name: 'Customer Rating'}
   {name: 'Sale'},
   {name: 'Shipping'}
]
```

Bonus points for es6 one liner solutions!

Comment: I think you'll have to explain more thoroughly what you mean by "sort this array so that a specific item is at a given index?" - Of course there is, but how are you sorting it currently? It seems like a pretty broad question to me.

Comment: We don't know what order the array given to us is in, and we want to transform this array into one where a specific element is always at a given index.

Comment: So you want to find an element with a given name and move it to an index?

Comment: looks like you already sorted it yourself

Answer (score 3):

Find element with name:

```
let i = arr.findIndex(item => item.name === 'Customer Rating');
```

Remove item:

```
let [item] = arr.splice(i, 1);
```

Insert item:

```
arr.splice(1, 0, item);
```

Don’t put this in one line:

```
arr.splice(1, 0, ...arr.splice(arr.findIndex(x => x.name=='Customer Rating'), 1));
```

```js
let arr = [
   {name: 'Price'},
   {name: 'Sale'},
   {name: 'Shipping'},
   {name: 'Customer Rating'}
];

let i = arr.findIndex(item => item.name === 'Customer Rating');
let [item] = arr.splice(i, 1);
arr.splice(1, 0, item);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` and `find`:

```js
var arr = [
   {name: 'Price'},
   {name: 'Sale'},
   {name: 'Shipping'},
   {name: 'Customer Rating'}
];

var sorted = ['Price', 'Customer Rating', 'Sale', 'Shipping']
.map(e => arr.find(({name}) => name === e));

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: That looks quadratic time. Also not sure that the OP has `['Price', 'Customer Rating', 'Sale', 'Shipping']`.

Comment: This only returns the items specified in the array. I think the idea was to specify the locations of certain objects, not all of them.

Comment: It guarantees order of all the elements, not just one. Anyway, thanks for comments!

Answer (score 0):

Find an object based on a passed in name, remove it, and then add it back in at the specified index. You can do this using [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
let setIndex = (arr, index, namevalue) => {
 arr.splice(arr.findIndex( ({name}) => name == namevalue ), 1);
 arr.splice(index, 0, {name: namevalue});
 return arr;
}
```

```js
var arr = [
   {name: 'Price'},
   {name: 'Sale'},
   {name: 'Shipping'},
   {name: 'Customer Rating'}
]

let setIndex = (arr, index, namevalue) => {
  arr.splice(arr.findIndex( ({name}) => name == namevalue ), 1);
  arr.splice(index, 0, {name: namevalue});
  return arr;
}

arr = setIndex(arr, 0, 'Customer Rating');

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a swap rather than a sort.

Like the answer above, you will need to find the element first.

> ```
> let i = arr.findIndex(item => item.name === 'Customer Rating');
> ```

Then jump over to this answer for the rest.

[Javascript swap array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872310/javascript-swap-array-elements)