# Snake Console Algorithm c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, console-application

Can someone explain me the logic part? I kinda know it should work but I cant trace the code step by step, It doesnt make sense. Exchange among temp, pre, and Tail part is so confusing.

How does it run with the framerate? Is TailX[0] and TailY[0] always ahead? WHY? How do new tail parts get assigned in correct position?
HELP ME.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Projects
{

class Snake
{
    public Random rand = new Random();
    public ConsoleKeyInfo keypress = new ConsoleKeyInfo();

    int score, headX, headY, fruitX, fruitY, nTail;

    int[] TailX = new int[100];
    int[] TailY = new int[100];

    const int height = 20;
    const int width = 60;

    bool gameOver, reset, isprinted, horizontal, vertical;

    string dir, pre_dir;

    void ShowBanner()
    {
        Console.SetWindowSize(width, height + 6);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.CursorVisible = false;

        Console.WriteLine("!!####################################!!");
        Console.WriteLine("!!####################################!!");
        Console.WriteLine("!!####################################!!");
        Console.WriteLine("!!####################################!!");
        Console.WriteLine("!!####################################!!");
        Console.WriteLine("!!##########     Welcome    ##########!!");

        keypress = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }

    void Setup()
    {
        dir = "Right";
        pre_dir = "";
        score = 0;
        nTail = 0;

        gameOver = false;
        reset = false;
        isprinted = false;

        headX = width / 2;
        headY = height / 2;
        fruitX = rand.Next(1, width - 1);
        fruitY = rand.Next(1, height - 1);
    }

    void CheckInput()
    {

        while (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            keypress = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                Environment.Exit(0);

            if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
            {
                pre_dir = dir;
                dir = "STOP";
            }

            else if (keypress.Key ==ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
            {
                pre_dir = dir;
                dir = "LEFT";
            }

            else if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                pre_dir = dir;
                dir = "RIGHT";
            }

            else if (keypress.Key ==ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                pre_dir = dir;
                dir = "UP";
            }


            else if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                pre_dir = dir;
                dir = "DOWN";
            }
        }
    }

    void Logic()
    {
        int preX = TailX[0];
        int preY = TailY[0];

        int tempX, tempY;

        if (dir != "STOP")
        {
            TailX[0] = headX;
            TailY[0] = headY;

            for (int i = 1; i < nTail; i++)
            {
                tempX = TailX[i];
                tempY = TailY[i];
                TailX[i] = preX;
                TailY[i] = preY;
                preX = tempX;
                preY = tempY;
            }
        }

        switch (dir)
        {
            case "RIGHT":
                headX++;
                break;

            case "LEFT":
                headX--;
                break;

            case "UP":
                headY--;
                break;

            case "DOWN":
                headY++;
                break;

            case "STOP":

                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.CursorLeft = width / 2 - 6;
                    Console.WriteLine("GAME PAUSED");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("   -S to resume   ");
                    Console.WriteLine("   -R to reset   ");
                    Console.Write("   -ESC to quit   ");

                    keypress = Console.ReadKey(true);

                    if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.R)
                    {
                        reset = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
                        break;
                }

                dir = pre_dir;
                break;
        }

        if (headX <= 0 || headX >= width - 1 || headY <= 0 || headY >= height - 1)
        {
            gameOver = true;
        }
        else
        {
            gameOver = false;
        }

        if (headX == fruitX && headY == fruitY)
        {
            score += 10;
            nTail++;

            fruitX = rand.Next(1, width - 1);
            fruitY = rand.Next(1, height - 1);
        }

        if (((dir == "LEFT" && pre_dir != "UP") && (dir == "LEFT" && pre_dir != "DOWN")) ||
          ((dir == "RIGHT" && pre_dir != "UP") && (dir == "RIGHT" && pre_dir != "DOWN")))
        {
            horizontal = true;
        }

        else
        {
            horizontal = false;
        }

        if (((dir == "UP" && pre_dir != "LEFT") && (dir == "UP" && pre_dir != "RIGHT")) ||
          ((dir == "DOWN" && pre_dir != "LEFT") && (dir == "RIGHT" && pre_dir != "RIGHT")))
        {
            vertical = true;
        }
        else
        {
            vertical = false;
        }


        for (int i = 1; i < nTail; i++)
        {
            if (TailX[i] == headX && TailY[i] == headY)
            {
                if (horizontal || vertical)
                {
                    gameOver = false;
                }

                else
                {
                    gameOver = true;
                }
            }

            if (TailX[i] == fruitX && TailY[i] == fruitY)
            {
                fruitX = rand.Next(1, width - 1);
                fruitY = rand.Next(1, height - 1);
            }
        }
    }


    void Render()

    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || i == height - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("#");
                }

                else if (j == 0 || j == width - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("#");
                }
                else if (j == fruitX && i == fruitY)
                {
                    Console.Write("F");
                }

                else if (j == headX && i == headY)
                {
                    Console.Write("0");
                }

                else
                {
                    isprinted = false;

                    for (int k = 0; k < nTail; k++)
                    {
                        if (TailX[k] == j && TailY[k] == i)
                        {
                            Console.Write("o");
                            isprinted = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!isprinted)
                        Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(" YOUR SCORE : " + score);
    }


    void Lose()
    {
        Console.CursorTop = height + 3;
        Console.CursorLeft = width / 2 - 4;
        Console.WriteLine("YOU DIED");
        Console.WriteLine(" R to reset");
        Console.Write(" Esc to quit");

        while (true)
        {
            keypress = Console.ReadKey(true);

            if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.R)
            {
                reset = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        while (!gameOver)
        {
            CheckInput();
            Logic();
            Render();
            if (reset)
                break;
            Thread.Sleep(30);
        }
        if (gameOver)
            Lose();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Snake snake = new Snake();
        snake.ShowBanner();
        while (true)
        {
            snake.Setup();
            snake.Update();

            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does headX and headY move when it still is in for loop? if not then TailX[i] and TailY[i] are always have to be equal to [0] right? if so how does parts follow head? HELPP

Comment: The `Logic` function is quite logical :) - first it temporarily stores the position of the head of the snake in `preX/preY`. It then sets the first element in the `TailX/Y` array to the position of the head (which will have been updated to a new position from the previous logic loop based on what direction you pressed). It then loops over each element and sets the new position to be the position of the element before it. That way, the head is in the right place, and the first segment of the tail is just where the head was last loop, and each segment is where the preceding segment was last loop

Comment: Think of it like "after we got our new head position, for each segment after that, set it's position to where the segment after it was last frame" - each segment updates into the X/Y position of the segment after it. The reason for the temp variable is to track the previous segments position so it can be swapped - you need a temp variable when you  swap elements in an array. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872310/javascript-swap-array-elements (look at the first code block in the accepted answer)

Comment: where I am having trouble is, when we get our first body part which is TailX/Y[1], we store its value to temp which is 0 right? then we pass preX/Y to TailX/Y which is TailX/Y[0] values, then again we pass temp to pre which is 0 again. So in every loop pre becomes 0 again, doesnt it? I think so anyway. I know Im making a mistake here but dont know where.

Comment: I mean initially all we have for TailX/Y[1] is 0 before we assign preX/Y to it in the for loop. So we give its value which is 0 to temp, then we pass preX and Y values to Tail, but our temp is still 0, then we pass temps value which is 0 to pre. where am I making the mistake here

Comment: Yes you are correct - `TailX[i]` (where `i >= 1`) will be zero the first time round the loop - but why does that matter? The head position gets stored in element `[0]` and the loop only looks into `TailX/TailY` to the length of `nTail` (which is the length of the snake). So we don't do any updates on the first frame, but later on, `nTail` increases by 1 (when you get food) and the loop remembers the head position from the last frame and copies that into element 1 becoming the tail position, the head is now in the new position in element 0.

Comment: Remember `nTail` starts at zero. `nTail` is the tail length, not the snake length. So if you look at the loop condition `for (int i = 1; i < nTail; i++)` - this never gets executed on the first frame.

Comment: So the loop only works after we have eaten at least 2 foods, right? after we ate first food, since we havent entered the loop, how does that gets in the right place?

Comment: I mean how does it know to be on TailX/Y[1] since we dont have any values for it?

Comment: Because `TailX` is the positions of the tail, not the head. The `Logic` loop always sets the position of the first element in the tail to the position of the head on the last frame. The renderer always renders a `0` at the position of `headX/headY` and loops from element `[0]` in the `TailX/Y` array to the length of `nTail` and renders a `o` for each tail element. It's actually a strange approach but I suppose it works fine. I probably wouldn't have written it quite like this - but there are many ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: frame means every time logic runs right?

Comment: Yes, frame is every time the `Logic` function runs. I think you are getting confused because `Logic` *always* sets a position for `TailX/Y[0]` but the `Render` function doesn't use it until `nTail` is 1 (because `TailX[0]` is the first **tail** position, not the head of the snake)

Comment: so  every time we pass headX/Y values to TailX/Y[0] our head is actually  one frame ahead from the value we pass?

Comment: Yes (because the update for position of headX/Y happens *after* the tail is updated).

Comment: Also, it's pretty buggy - you can eat your own tail and not die (most of the time), and some of the walls disappear if you go backwards on yourself (which isn't allowed in snake)! :)

Comment: yeah I have been encountering those too, but I just wanna grasp how the algorithm works here

Comment: can you explain together with values of pre, temp, head, and Tail[i], when i is 0,1 and 2. I think that will clear my head. Like what is those values when i is 0,1,2? you can make up head values of course, just I wanna know what happens with pre temp and tail[i] during that

Comment: I'll write up an answer later - just busy at the mo :)

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so let's run through the `Logic` function with different values of `i`.

`i` represents the number of loops to do in the `Logic` function up to the length of the snake which is given by `nTail`, however, it starts from 1, not 0 so it skips the first tail segment which is always set to where the head was last frame.

**When the snake is just a head `nTail = 0`**

Before you eat food, `nTail` is 0 and therefore the only part of the logic that runs is:

```
// Set the position of the first segment of the tail to the position of where the head was this frame
TailX[0] = headX;
TailY[0] = headY;
```

and then a bit later in the function

```
// Set a new position for the head of the snake based on direction
switch (dir)
{
    case "RIGHT":
        headX++;
    break;

    // etc...
```

In this example, assuming the snake is moving right (let's ignore Y and just look at X).

```
headX = 5;
TailX[0] = 4;
```

Let's now assume you ate some food so `nTail = 1`

**When the snake has 1 segment of tail `nTail = 1`**

The same thing happens as in the first state - the loop is skipped.

Since the function is already setting the position of the tail to be the position of the head, and then updating the head, we still have the same situation, except we are just moved along another tile (update `TailX[0]` to position of `headX`, then update `headX` based on the direction we are travelling).

```
headX = 6;
TailX[0] = 5;
```

What happens now when you get more food on the next turn (apart from being lucky)?

**When the snake has 2 segments of tail `nTail = 2`**

Now the `Logic` loop runs the tail update loop because `nTail` is now large enough for the loop condition to trigger.

Now remember that we already updated `TailX[0]` to be the same as `headX` - so we know that the first segment of the tail is already in the place that the head was last frame.

Now we loop through all of the other tail segments and set their position to the place where the previous tail segment was.

This is why `preX` is important. At the start of the function we capture the position of the first tail segment `preX = TailX[0]`.

Then when we get to the loop. We only loop once because `nTail = 1`, so (I've excluded the Y as we only need X to demonstrate)

```
for (int i = 1; i < nTail; i++)
{
    // Capture the X position of the current segment of tail as we will need it to update the next segment of tail 
    tempX = TailX[i];
    // Set the X position of the tail to the previous tail segment (remember, we captured this at the start of the logic function and it was essentially the X position of the head)
    TailX[i] = preX;
    // Capture the old position of the tail segment pre-update so we can assign it to the next tail segment
    preX = tempX;
}

// Later on we update the head to its new position
```

So this results in:

```
headX = 7;
TailX[0] = 6;
TailX[1] = 5;
```

So you have to think about the algorithm backwards as that's how it works:

- Update the first segment of tail to where the head is
- Update any other segments of tail to where the previous segment was
- Update the head to move to a new position

Important to also note that the render function always renders the head using `headX/Y` and only renders the tail if `nTail` is greater than 0.

This explains why, even though `TailX[0]` is set every frame regardless of the snake length, you don't see the tail until you eat food.

**Addendum:**

Couple of bugs that exist:

- You can go backwards and run into your tail - this sometimes kills you, but most of the time doesn't. If your head is on a part of your tail, some of the arena walls don't render. I've not looked at why but I noticed this in gameplay.
- The play area is 20 * 60, if we subtract 1 from each dimension (top/bottom/left/right) for the walls, we end up with a playable area of 18 * 58 which means the max length of the snake can technically be 1,044. The arrays aren't big enough and getting to a length of 101 will crash the game (index out of range) - I spotted this in the code and recreated the scenario in VS:

[image: oops, bugs!]

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend! I appreciate this so much! Thank you!