# Swap object items in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an **obj** in which need to swap **title** and **id** elements inside, **priority** remains in place.

```
const obj= [{id: 300, priority: 1, title: "title 1"}
            {id: 301, priority: 2, title: "title 2"}
            {id: 302, priority: 3, title: "title 3"}
            {id: 303, priority: 4, title: "title 4"}];
```

Should get this:

```
const obj= [{id: 301, priority: 1, title: "title 2"}
            {id: 300, priority: 2, title: "title 1"}
            {id: 302, priority: 3, title: "title 3"}
            {id: 303, priority: 4, title: "title 4"}];
```

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us? Even if it does not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872310/javascript-swap-array-elements

Comment: In this case,  swapping `priority` would be easier since you are swapping only one property.

Comment: Your question is not clear. On what condition you want to swap `title` and `id` ?

Comment: re-order them and then do a `.map` on the array to set the priority for all elements

Comment: Try: `arr.sort((x, y) => x.priority - y.priority)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a swap operation in JS.

```js
function swap(source, id1, id2) {
    if (parseInt(id1) > source.length || parseInt(id2) > source.length) {
        throw "Out of source range"
    }
    [source[id1].id, source[id2].id] = [source[id2].id, source[id1].id];
    [source[id1].title, source[id2].title] = [source[id2].title, source[id1].title];
}

obj = [{id: 300, priority: 1, title: "title 1"},
        {id: 301, priority: 2, title: "title 2"},
        {id: 302, priority: 3, title: "title 3"},
        {id: 303, priority: 4, title: "title 4"}];
swap(obj, 0, 1);
console.log(obj);
```

Remember this will overwrite the source object. If you want to return the copy you need to copy element in the function.

Comment: When you do a snippet then also call your function and demonstrate it