# Swap in JavaScript List

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers

I used to be a C programmer & new in JavaScript and use pointers to swap elements of an array using

```
void swap(int *a,int *b){
     int temp=*a;
     *a=*b;
    *b=temp;

 }
```

What will be the equivalent function of this in JavaScript?

Comment: This may nasser you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872310/javascript-swap-array-elements

Comment: You cannot do that in JavaScript, at least not in a way that's a general as how it can be done in C or C++. JavaScript doesn't have a pointer type that can be used as flexibly as that.

Comment: Js has no low-level memory management - data is either primitive or reference type (https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-primitive-vs-reference-values/) So, if it is int (number in js), it'll be copied by value. Objects'll be copied by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement some of pointer logic using [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) and its views like [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) with helpers like [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder).

```
var memory = new TextEncoder().encode("HelloWorld");

// create pointers in memory
var H = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, 0, 1);
var W = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, 5, 1);

// create string from byte array
const toString = buf => String.fromCharCode.apply(null, buf);

// swap two bytes in memory
function swap(a, b) {
    [a[0],b[0]] = [b[0],a[0]];
}

swap(H, W);
console.log(toString(memory)); // WelloHorld
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your array from `[1,2,3]` to `[{val: 1}, {val:2}, {val: 3}]` and use such approach:

```
const swap = (a, b) => {
  const val = a.val;
  a.val = b.val;
  b.val = val;
}
```

Array contains the same references with new vals.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can pass the references of variables by grouping them in an object.
So let's say you have two variables x and y... They have to be enclosed in an object.

```
const values = {
    x : 1,
    y : 3
}
```

We can pass them as one object to the swap function:

```
swap(values)
```

And inside the function we can swap them like so:

```
function swap (obj) {
    let temp = obj.x
    obj.x = obj.y
    obj.y = temp
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript/)

this method has a flaw though as you have to pass the values named x and y to the swap function. We can tweak the function to be more dynamic as follows:

```
function swap (obj) {
    let temp = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]
    obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]] = obj[Object.keys(obj)[1]]
    obj[Object.keys(obj)[1]] = temp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet works as an equivalent :

```
function swap(arr, from, to) {
  arr.splice(from, 1, arr.splice(to, 1, arr[from])[0]);
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52225064/14859542

Comment: This is functionally equivalent, but walks through large portion of the array, which does matter in long arrays. Beeing C coder like you, I provided my answer to swap two locations in memory.

Comment: I am going through your solution. I will revert to you if I have any confusion.

Answer (score -1):

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;

console.log("Before Swap");
console.log("value a: " + a);
console.log("value b: " + b);

[a, b] = [b, a];

console.log("After swap");
console.log("value a: " + a);
console.log("value b: " + b);
```

You can use Destructuring Assignment in order to swap a value. I also just learned it. Please correct me if im wrong, im also new to JavaScript

Comment: This will copy values, so such approach cannot be used in function